# Where in Laravel folders do i put my AIMEOS ecommerce extension after overriting the html template behaviour?

Tags: laravel

I am building a laravel e-commerce web site using [AIMEOS Ecommerce framework](https://aimeos.org) , i went through the documentation to find how to adapt the default HTML template with my own HTML.
I found how to do it by generating the extension [here on AIMEOS website](https://aimeos.org/extensions).

**I am stacked at where to put the modified extension files within my laravel folders.**

Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your modified files in the ./ext//client/html/templates/ folder in the same directory structure as in the ai-client-html extension, e.g.

```
./ext/ai-client-html/client/html/templates/catalog/detail/body-standard.php
```

store modified file in

```
./ext/<yourextname>/client/html/templates/catalog/detail/body-standard.php
```